# Templated constexpr function invocation with partially defined class changes subsequent results

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, constexpr

I have a struct with multiple overloads of a static function taking some `counter<int>` as an argument:

```
struct S {
    static void fn(counter<1>);
    static void fn(counter<2>);
    static void fn(counter<3>);
};
```

A templated `constexpr` function can be used to look for a specific overload in that class:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr size_t count_fns() {
    // 'defines_fn' is a type trait, full code in demo link
    if constexpr (defines_fn<T, counter<99> >::value) { return  99; }
    if constexpr (defines_fn<T, counter<98> >::value) { return  98; }
    if constexpr (defines_fn<T, counter<97> >::value) { return  97; }
    // [...]
    if constexpr (defines_fn<T, counter<3> >::value) { return  3; }
    if constexpr (defines_fn<T, counter<2> >::value) { return  2; }
    if constexpr (defines_fn<T, counter<1> >::value) { return  1; }
    return 0;
}
```

In ordinary usage, `count_fns<S>()` returns 3, as expected.

However, adding an inline static variable invoking `count_fns` changes things:

```
struct U {
    static void fn(counter<1>);
    static void fn(counter<2>);
    static constexpr size_t C0 = count_fns<U>();  // C0 is 2
    static void fn(counter<3>);
};

static_assert(count_fns<U>() == 3, " <-- fails, value is actually 'still' 2");
```

Godbolt suggests this behavior is consistent across compilers (MSVC, gcc, clang):
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qsEvocEcn)

Is this to be expected, or is it some sort of undefined behavior with the constexpr interpreter?

---

These are the definitions of `counter` and `defines_fn`:

```
template <size_t Value>
struct counter {
    static constexpr size_t value = Value;
};

template <typename T, typename Arg, class = void>
struct defines_fn { static constexpr bool value = false; };

template <typename T, typename Arg>
struct defines_fn<T, Arg, std::void_t<decltype(T::fn(std::declval<Arg>()))> >
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Comment: You are instantiating a template at a point where the type you instantiate for is not yet complete. Though I'm not fully sure about this indeed has pretty much the smell of UB...

Comment: When you write `static constexpr size_t C0 = count_fns<U>();` the function is instantiated and then later it is reused because of the ODR (one definition rule). One could argue that your later use of `count_fns<U>()` violates the ODR since now the definition of the function would be different. What I'm unsure about is that the first `count_fns<U>` instatiation shoud be placed after the defintion of `U`. So why doesn't it return 3 in the first place?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments below the answer you accepted, the template case is a different question, or at least it's sufficiently different that it shouldn't be added after an answer has been posted. You can post a new question about that if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section of the standard that is supposed to govern this kind of code is [[temp.point]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point). Unfortunately, it's considered to be defective. [CWG 287](https://wg21.link/cwg287)

The standard technically says that in your example, where `count_fns<U>` is referenced inside the definition of `U`, the point of instantiation is considered to be right after the definition of `U`. However, this leads to absurdities; what should happen if, for example, we had the following declaration inside `U`:

```
static void fn(counter<2 * C0>);
```

Now it seems that we have a circular dependency.

CWG 287 concerned *class* template specializations. The issue with those is a bit different because [temp.point] says that (for example) if you were to reference a class template specialization within the definition of `U` then the point of instantiation would be *before* the definition of `U`. (I haven't yet figured out why the rules are different for class templates and function templates.)

To solve the issues in both cases, it seems the "common sense" approach is that both template and non-template constructs referenced from inside a class definition should be able to see previously declared members of the class (and this holds for both function and class template specializations). (If the context from which they're referenced is a complete-class context, they should be able to see all members of the class. Is that possible or does it lead to other issues? I'm not sure. So I'm going to just avoid this issue for now.)

Following that principle, if the initializer of `C0` requires a template specialization, compilers seem to place the point of instantiation either right before or right after the declaration of `C0`. There is implementation divergence on whether it's before or after, but in any case, it's after the member declarations that precede `C0`, and before the member declarations that follow `C0`. All major compilers seem to agree on this point.

The second instantiation of `count_fns<U>`, in the `static_assert` declaration, references the same set of specializations of the `defines_fn` class template as the first instantiation did. *Class* template specializations, unlike function template specializations, are not re-instantiated every time they are referenced; the *first* instantiation is "cached". See [temp.point] p4 and p7. So the second call to `count_fns<U>` returns the same result as the first.

So that seems to be the reason why you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing. Whether it's right or wrong, we can't say, until CWG 287 is fixed.

Comment: Great answer, although there's something I'm not sure it fully explains; changing `U` into a templated class in this example results in `C0` being `2` while `count_fns` outside of the definition will return `3`. Why doesn't the `defines_fn` "caching" apply in that case?

Comment: @JackHarwood Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "making `U` a template class". If you want to ask a question about *different* code, post a new question.

Comment: I edited in an example; I was mistaken, both `C0` and the "external" call will be `3` on compilers that accept the templated case (MSVC rejects it), so the "caching" still holds.

Comment: @JackHarwood The example with `V` is different because [temp.point]/1 has a different rule about where the point of instantiation is for `count_fns<V>` if it's referenced from within some other template specialization. But here the wording is also unclear and might lead to other issues. It really deserves a totally separate question.